# typescript: непонятная ошибка с типами

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

есть данные о городах и их координатах:

```
[
    {
        "country": "AD",
        "name": "Sant Julià de Lòria",
        "lat": "42.46372",
        "lng": "1.49129"
    },
    {
        "country": "AD",
        "name": "Pas de la Casa",
        "lat": "42.54277",
        "lng": "1.73361"
    },
    и т.д.
]
```

которую записываю в переменную:

```
import citiesCoords from 'cities.json'
```

Я ищу записи по городу и стране в данном Json:

```
const cities: IType_City[] = citiesCoords.filter((obj: IType_City) => obj.name === city && obj.country === country);
```

и typescript подчёркивает `filter` и выдает следующее:

```
any
Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
No quick fixes available
```

сами типы такие:

```
// интерфейс для данных о городах
export interface IType_City {
    country:        string,         // буквенный код страны
    name:           string,         // название города
    lat:            string,         // долгота
    lng:            string          // широта
}
```

Как исправить ошибку без использования типа `any`?

Как я понимаю всё дело в том, что полученные из json данные неизвестного типа и мне как-то надо указать, что это `IType_City[]`?

Comment: какой тип показывает ide при наведении на citiesCoords ?

Comment: может `= (citiesCoords as IType_City[]).filter` ?

Comment: никакого - пишет `import citiesCoords`

Comment: Дмитрий, помогло! Но вот, что странно я таким же способом через `filter` вытягиваю информацию из другого json (со странами), там ровно тоже самое, но ошибки никакой не показывает

Comment: в английском SO еще подсказывают конструкцию `import foo : IFoo from "foo"`, попробуйте

Comment: _но ошибки никакой не показывает_ возможно там простая структура. В вашем примере ошибка из-за того, что ts воспринимает `citiesCoords` не как массив, а как объект с числовыми ключами.

Comment: если вы про `import citiesCoords: IType_City[] from `, то такая конструкция не сработала :( ошибка